# A nonplanar closed curve such that the plane curve with the same curvature as function of the arclength is not closed

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves, curvature

Find a non plane, closed curve such that the plane curve with the same curvature as function of the arclength is not closed.

Been thinking a lot in this problem and haven't got a clue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure this is even possible?